# What's the difference between "ask that you" and "ask you to"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is there any subtle connotational difference between the two passages below?

> I just **ask that you** keep an eye on my nephew while I am doing the
>   morning errands outside, which won't detract even a bit from the
>   quality of your preparation for the test.
>
> I just **ask you to** keep an eye on my nephew while I am doing the
>   morning errands outside, which won't detract even a bit from the
>   quality of your preparation for the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in grammar here just makes the first version sound more *formal*. It uses **subjunctive** form of the verb to keep (technically, it's bare infinitive); the difference would be more visible in the 3rd person (you -> *he/she*):

> 'I ask that **he keep**... [not keep**s**]'.

This form of subjunctive clause (coming from old original English) is now more typical for American English, in British English clauses with 'should' (before the bare infinitive) are preferred.